# Getting Correct Date From JSON Formatted Value

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am having trouble converting a JSON formatted timestamp to an NSDate in Xcode.

For example, I get the following formatted timestamp returned from my RESTful web service:  "/Date(1369835402000)/".

**[EDIT]**

Making this edit for clarity of the value I am actually getting returned and value I am passing in:

When I convert the above timestamp to an NSDate I get a time that is as follows:

[image: date is 1 hour ahead of actual timestamp]

As you can see the date returned is 1 hour ahead of the actual date even though I am not setting timezone.

I am now using the following method to convert the timestamp to a date:

```
- (NSDate*) getDateFromJSON:(NSString *)dateString
{
// Expect date in this format "/Date(1369835402000)/"
int startPos = [dateString rangeOfString:@"("].location+1;
int endPos = [dateString rangeOfString:@")"].location;
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(startPos,endPos-startPos);
unsigned long long milliseconds = [[dateString substringWithRange:range] doubleValue];
NSLog(@"%llu",milliseconds);
NSTimeInterval interval = milliseconds/1000;
return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
}
```

but it still returns the value as 1 hour ahead.

[EDIT]

The requested DUMP from NSLog is below plus the code that creates it:

```
- (NSDate*) getDateFromJSON:(NSString *)dateString
{
// Expect date in this format "/Date(1369835402000)/"
int startPos = [dateString rangeOfString:@"("].location+1;
int endPos = [dateString rangeOfString:@")"].location;
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(startPos,endPos-startPos);
unsigned long long milliseconds = [[dateString substringWithRange:range] longLongValue];

NSTimeInterval interval = milliseconds/1000;
NSLog(@"%f", interval);
NSLog(@"%@", [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval]);

interval -= 3600;
return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
}
```

SAMPLE DUMP:

```
2013-05-30 09:58:47.616 Log[13734:907] 1365693200.000000
2013-05-30 09:58:47.619 Log[13734:907] 2013-04-11 15:13:20 +0000
2013-05-30 09:58:47.620 Log[13734:907] 2013-04-11 14:13:20 +0000
2013-05-30 09:58:47.621 Log[13734:907] 1358157335.000000
2013-05-30 09:58:47.622 Log[13734:907] 2013-01-14 09:55:35 +0000
2013-05-30 09:58:47.622 Log[13734:907] 2013-01-14 08:55:35 +0000
2013-05-30 09:58:47.628 Log[13734:907] 1365684042.000000
2013-05-30 09:58:47.629 Log[13734:907] 2013-04-11 12:40:42 +0000
2013-05-30 09:58:47.630 Log[13734:907] 2013-04-11 11:40:42 +0000
2013-05-30 09:58:47.632 Log[13734:907] 1358157374.000000
2013-05-30 09:58:47.632 Log[13734:907] 2013-01-14 09:56:14 +0000
2013-05-30 09:58:47.633 Log[13734:907] 2013-01-14 08:56:14 +0000
2013-05-30 09:58:47.638 Log[13734:907] 1365684238.000000
2013-05-30 09:58:47.639 Log[13734:907] 2013-04-11 12:43:58 +0000
2013-05-30 09:58:47.640 Log[13734:907] 2013-04-11 11:43:58 +0000
```

The first row is the interval output.
Second is after the conversion using dateWithTimeInteralSince1970 and shows the 1 hour added automatically.
Third is the return value from function from where I call it - shows the manually subtracted hour (-3600).

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do with "offset" above.  I don't see anywhere where you use it.

Comment: Maybe you should post what result you actually get from your value at the top of the question.  ([The web](http://www.epochconverter.com/) gives me Mon, 13 May 2013 18:07:01 GMT.)

Comment: (And what timezone are you in?)

Comment: @HotLicks I have edited my question for clarity.  I am in GMT timezone. When I convert "/Date(1369835402000)/" at epochconverter.com I get "Wed, 29 May 2013 13:50:02 GMT" but as you can see above I get "2013-05-29 14:50:02 IST" from my method above which is 1 hour ahead of the actual value I passed in.

Comment: IST is India Standard Time, which is quite curious.  Have you dumped your NSDate with plain old NSLog, without formatting it??

Comment: IST is actually "Irish Summer Time" but it's even more curious because I am not formatting the timestamp with any timezone yet it is still returning GMT+1 based on the settings in simulator (also on physical iPad).

Comment: if I add the line "interval -= 3600;" to my getDateFromJSON method I get the correct time but this will return the wrong time in future when Irish Summer Time reverts back to GMT.

Comment: @HotLicks have updated my question above with the dump from NSLog and updated code. thanks for your help on it.

Comment: Uh, 15:13:20, 09:55:35, and 12:40:42 are correct.  Your "corrected" values are one hour off.

Comment: There was no intention to waste your time.  The issue remains unresolved for me.  But thanks for your time and thoughts.

Comment: I don't understand how "the issue is unresolved" if the code was giving the right answer all along.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it:

```
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:([[self stringBetween:@"Date(" and:@")"] doubleValue] / 1000)];
```

Where stringBetween:and: does as its name implies.

Comment: thank you for replying.  When I use your suggestion I get a date in 1970. I have edited the method above in dateFromDotNet:

Comment: I'm also getting IST time even though my system time is set to GMT.  The time stored in my backend is correct.

Comment: Running this in the simulator: NSLog(@"%@", [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:([@"1368468421000" doubleValue] / 1000)]); Gives me the output: "2013-05-13 18:07:01 +0000"

Comment: apologies I was passing in an incorrect value which was giving back the 1970 date and time.  The issue above is still happening though - I am getting a GMT + 1 hour returned date.  It is giving me an hour ahead of the time I am passing in even though I am not specifically formatting the timezone.

Comment: @motionpotion - You've not at all defined how you're looking at the date produced by the various algorithms.  If you simply NSLog the date it should give you GMT.  There are many ways to foul up formatting it.  (And what do you consider to be the "correct" value?)

Comment: @HotLicks have edited question above for clarity of the value I am passing in and what is being returned.  It's returning GMT + 1 back but I cannot figure out why.

Comment: @HotLicks I consider the correct value to be the value I passed in without the added 1 hour.